# Transistor array with a common base

Tags: transistors, integrated-circuit, parallel

I'm looking for a transistor array IC with a common base to all the transistors, but I'm having some trouble finding what I'm looking for. Essentially, what I want is to take 8 data lines in parallel and be able to (somewhat rapidly) switch them on and off - that is, for 8 lines, switch all of them on and all of them off with one input line. I can do this with 8 individual transistors, splitting the input line itself into 8 parallel bases, but I'm hoping some actual EE out there - i.e., not a dabbler like me - knows of a nice little chip that will do the trick and save me some soldering.

You can imagine what it's like trying to search for "transistor integrated circuit", but that's what I want - an IC with 8 NPN transistors, all of which take their base off of one pin.

MORE DETAIL:

I'm attempting to drive quite a few 14 segment dual digit LED displays (like [this one](http://www.us.kingbright.com/images/catalog/SPEC/PDA54-12YWA.pdf) - the internal circuit diagram is important to this issue) with a fancy little LED display driver [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5940.pdf) (details less important. Fancy 16 bit shift register.) The LED driver has some nice features that would be annoying to duplicate, like individually-controllable PWM dimming for each segment, and this would be just fine with a seven segment LCD without multiplexing. Shift in the bits, latch it up, and we're good.

Unfortunately, the 14 segment LCD's only seem to work through multiplexing, as you have 8 input pins that are multiplexed among 4 different "regions" by choosing the anode. You can't just latch the bits you want on the driver and forget it - you need to control the bits as a combination of anodes and cathodes.

What I'm thinking of now is to drive a closed loop shift register with e.g. `0001` in a loop and choose the 8 cathode inputs by `and`-ing or switching them 8 at a time out of 32 latched input lines (that is, 2 of the driver chips, but only 8 bits of those chips at any one time). This way I *would* be able to shift the desired bits into the registers and ignore the whole circuit from the microprocessor's point of view (minus the shift merry-go-round clock pulse, which is minor). Just let it round-robin multiplex itself until I want to come back and display something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using a [74HC240](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT240.pdf) or [74HC244](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT244.pdf) tri-state buffer IC and use the OE input to switch multiple outputs?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a source for these ICs:

- [M54513P](http://www.mitsubishielectric.com/semiconductors/content/product/icsensor/transistorarray/tarray/tarray_lv4/m54513fp_e.pdf) is a plain 8 x 50mA NPN transistor array.
- [TLC59213](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc59213.pdf) is a more sophisticated choice for your application. All 8 outputs (current source, 500mA each) are latched and controlled by a common ~CLR input for shutdown.

Comment: Those are common emitter arrays, not common base.

Comment: The M54513P is an 18 pin DIP IC and all 8 input pins are on one side: pins 1-8. Connecting their pads would suffice the requirement: "what I want - an IC with 8 NPN transistors, all of which take their base off of one pin", I suppose? My understanding is that @Matt wants to avoid the trouble of soldering 8 discrete transistors. As far as I know, there are no generic common base transistor arrays. See http://www.nteinc.com/linear_web/array.php?a=12 as NTE (formerly ECG) is a benchmark for generic parts and replacements.